# Connecting VS2017-15.3.5 to macOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am trying to connect my Visual Studio 2017 for Community installed on windows 10 to macOS Sierra 10.12.6, here what I tried so far without success

**Settings On macOS**

1. I Installed the XCode V9
2. I enabled remote login for all users
3. After first try to login from visual studio a popup shown in macOS to install xcodebuild , and I did install it.

**Settings On Windows**

1. I Installed the Xamarin components
2. I tried to connect to the macOS machine appearing in the Xamarin Mac Agent, I provided the User name and the password, it took about 1 minute to notify me about the connection is failed
3. I tried to add the mac manually by providing the IP (192.168.1.10) and by providing the user name, same result

I followed the instructions mentioned on this [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/), but Xamarin Studio is not available anymore as download since it is contained inside visual studio application, and What I read also that there is no requirement anymore to install any further apps on macOS and only we need to allow the Remote Login.

What is missing in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by installing the Mono Framework and Xamarin Studio 6.1 from the following website [Mono Develop](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/)

Hope this will help another developer who was stuck like my case